# Button on hover does not reduce properly using keyframes

Tags: html, css, button, hover, css-animations

How can I make my button decrease size on hover as per this pen [here](https://codepen.io/woolandcotton/full/mBmLwq) looking at the pulse button?

My CSS looks like this:

```
.pulse {
  margin:100px;
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #cca92c;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
}

.pulse:hover {
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0%{
        width: 170px;
    }
    50%{
        width: 120px;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="pulse">Button styling</button>
```

When I hover, the width decreases, but the effect is not the same as the reference pen which gets smaller on all sides, if that's the correct explanation.

My pen can be found [here](https://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/XLEWRL)

Comment: you need to consider `scale()` not `width`

Comment: The pen uses `scale()` to create the pulse effect, not `width` https://codepen.io/woolandcotton/pen/mBmLwq

Comment: I think I didnt see the code because I was  not logged in. Appreciate the support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add transform to get the animation

```css
.pulse {
  margin: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #cca92c;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

.pulse:hover {
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(.9);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="pulse">Button styling</button>
```

Comment: sorry transform typo mistake :/

Comment: The only thing I notice is that the color tends to get blur once the transition starts and only at the end looks neat. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: no its just because the text is animated it look bit blur